# Can zombies attack me while riding minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In an underground mine I have several mine carts. Sometimes a zombie gets stuck in one and I'm afraid to go near them. Can they attack you if they are in the mine cart?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to my in-game testing, **no**, zombies cannot attack you when riding in a minecart. You can get as close as you would like to that zombie, and as long as he's still riding the cart, he's harmless.

Comment: as long as *he's* riding?